# How to change whole content of the page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Lately i've been building page and i've come accross one simple problem.
I want to change whole (mayby without navbar) content of the page depended on what user have clicked. But i dont know how to do it :(

I want to change whole content of div "halfDivided" on

### Home

or

### About

dependend on which link has been clicked

Plz help me guys :>

```html
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="mainDiv">
                <Navbar account={this.state.account} />
                <div className="d-flex halfDivided align-items-stretch ">
                <Link 
                to="/YourTokens" 
                className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
                >
                    <h1 className="display-2 a text-center">Your Tokens</h1>
                </Link>
                
                <Link 
                  to="/YourColors" 
                  className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
                >
                    <h1 className="display-2 a text-center">Your Colors</h1>
                </Link>
                </div>
                 <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/YourTokens" component={YourTokens} />
                    <Route exact path="/YourColors" component={YourColors} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
function YourTokens() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function YourColors() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: hey mate, we probably just need a bit more info to help you out on this one. What are you trying to change it to? What do you want to click to change it etc?

Comment: I want to change whole content of div "halfDivided" on <h2>Home</h2> or <h2>About</h2> dependend on which link has been clicked

Comment: Okay, no worries. Are you trying to render the YourTokens and YourColors components inside of "halfDivided" when the user clicks a link?

Comment: Yees and i want to make this 2 links, that are inside, invisible. So: before there are 2 links and after click links are going out and only <h2>Something<h2> disappears :)

Comment: Okay, hopefully I'm understanding correctly! Try creating a third "default" route and place it after the other two: <Route path="/" component={MyDefaultComponent} />. Note that "exact" is removed from this one. Then create a new default component and put your links in that. This way you'll only see the links if none of the other routes are active. Let me know if that works and I'll post it as a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from our discussion in the comments, hopefully this is what you're after:

```html
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="mainDiv">
                <Navbar account={this.state.account} />
                <div className="d-flex halfDivided align-items-stretch ">
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/YourTokens" component={YourTokens} />
                    <Route exact path="/YourColors" component={YourColors} />
                    <Route path="/" component={MyDefaultComponent} />
                </Switch>
                </div>                     
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
function YourTokens() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function YourColors() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function MyDefaultComponent() {
  return (
<>
    <Link 
                to="/YourTokens" 
                className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
                >
                    <h1 className="display-2 a text-center">Your Tokens</h1>
                </Link>
                
                <Link 
                  to="/YourColors" 
                  className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
                >
                    <h1 className="display-2 a text-center">Your Colors</h1>
                </Link>
</>
  );
}
```

What we're doing is creating a "default route" and rendering the links inside of it. This way the links will only be shown when none of the other routes are active.